# Why do these folders on a network drive have a link icon in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, network-shares, icons, links

My organization has a mapped network drive that everyone can access to share files. Inside that drive, there are two folders. Their icons are the normal folder icon, but they also have the shortcut/link icon in the bottom left corner:
[image: screenshot of folder]

These folders are neither Windows shortcuts (`.lnk`) nor symbolic links (`dir /a` lists them normally). Why is Windows indicating that they are links?

Comment: May be an indication that they are mapped drives/folders

Comment: @Moab Their subfolders are also on the mapped drive and they don't have the icon.

Comment: That is to be expected.

Comment: @Moab Could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: Only the Network shared folder has the icon not subfolders.

Comment: Is there a `desktop.ini` file in these folders (if so it will be hidden). What is the content of that file?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator There is not a `desktop.ini` in either folder.

Comment: @Moab The folders in the screenshot are subfolders of the network shared folder.